# Why does @FunctionalInterface have a RUNTIME retention?

Tags: java, java-8

[Said in Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> If a type is annotated with this annotation type, compilers are
>   required to generate an error message unless ...

Why isn't `SOURCE` or `CLASS` enough, like for `@Override`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation serves two purposes. Regarding the compiler and the error it has to generate it would be indeed enough to have a `SOURCE` `RetentionPolicy` as in this regard it only affects the very class annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`.

However, it has a second purpose, documenting the fact that using this `interface` as a functional interface is indeed intended and the possibility to use it this way not just a coincidence like with, e.g. `Comparable` which is not intended to be used that way.

Therefore it is annotated with `@Documented` and has the maximum `RetentionPolicy` to fulfill the second purpose.

Comment: Does each @Documented interface have the maximum RetentionPolicy (RUNTIME)?

Comment: @auntyellow: It’s not a hard requirement, however, it’s purpose of making the information broadly available leads to the conclusion that you usually *want* maximum retention. By the way `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` does not offer any advantage over `RUNTIME`. It consumes the same amount of space within a class file and since Reflection loads annotations only on demand, there is no benefit in not being available within the runtime either.

Answer (score 2):

"Source" would not be enough, since if for example you create an API and provide your class as a pre-compiled jar, the information would not be available for the compiler anymore.

I believe "class" would also not be enough if you want to support those kind of compilers that "compile" against a class at runtime, like scripting engines that use reflection to find out about those annotations and should show a warning, too.

Answer (score 1):

`@FunctionalInterface` is for runtime reflection, compile check, and java runtime process probably.

*javap* is used to de-compile and compare two interfaces, one with `@FunctionalInterface`, the other none.

Just extra two lines byte code in `@FunctionalInterface` tagged interface:

```
Constant pool:
   #7 = ...   RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
   #8 = ...   Ljava/lang/FunctionalInterface;
```

And both implementation/lambda express are same at byte code level.

Except for interface reflection:

```
X.class.getAnnotation(FunctionalInterface.class) == null?;
```